# Unity3d there was a problem parsing the package

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXZLy.png)

[Rest of the Project Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiCXd.png)

I'm only using a custom AndroidManifest.xml to set the android:exported property to true
and the issue keeps appearing with or without the custom manifest
I also tried to make a new keystore as well as using a keystore from another working project with a same and different alias (I tried both).
The Unity editor does not show any errors when building .
I also tried to export the project to see if any of the files would catch my attention and need to be edited, but I didn't find anything

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

this is my custom manifest and the only thing I added is the android:exported="true" in the  tag

I'm not that new to unity but this is my second game that I try to make for mobile so I don't have much experience with it yet

Thanks in advance!

ps I also tried changing the name of the apk/aab (tried both)

Comment: Why were you adding the tag? Does the problem go away if you revert the change? It sounds more like a package issue in the title not build. So its hard to say

Comment: I'm adding the tag because when I try to upload the aab to the play console it shows me this error "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported" also I tried the script in this link https://forum.unity.com/threads/game-doesnt-install-on-android-12-from-playstore.1222065/#post-7794402

Comment: but I think that the problem isn't the tag but rather that the fact that the file cannot be parsed which most likely means its corrupted or incomplete in some way and in a game I released before this one and it didn't have a problem parsing the package but had the same android:exported issue which I fixed using the custom manifest above and I think the android:exported is required for the ads (I think I read that somewhere but I'm not fully certain) and yes I did try deleting the tag or setting it to false and neither worked on the play store nor as an apk

Comment: I tried renaming the apk to the package name (mine is overridden so that would be com.SolenopsisCampo.JumpyTank) and I also tried naming it the product name only (JumpyTank) and I tried to name it like the project (Jumpy Tank) and there was some sort of android notifications package that came with the project, I tried to delete it but also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a package that didn't get uninstalled the correct way (it was uninstalled but unity still marked it as installed so yeah), double check that any package you wanted to uninstall actually got uninstalled and isnt available in the package manager